# Does Google correlate stop for Belgium in 2014?

Tags: europe

I calculated for each week in 2013 and 2014 the proportion sales amount of kids shoes to the total sales for a shoe shop in Belgium. Then, on [google correlate][1], I looked for correlated search terms.

I found significant results in the US (mainly soccer related) and the Netherlands (mainly children clothes related). In Belgium, I find significant results for my 2013 data (specifically September), but if I supply my 2014 data too, it finds nothing. If I supply only my 2013 for a search in the US or the Netherlands, I see the data for the correlated term is displayed for 2014 too, but not for Belgium.

What could explain this?

Comment: It looks like you're missing the external link you are referencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I think* this might be due to insufficient data or a change in Google's algorithms because there is data for Belgium when you search for mentions of the word "google": https://www.google.com/trends/correlate/search?e=google&t=weekly&p=be ; If you search for other words like "election" and "vote", the data for the second half of 2013 through present day for Belgium does appear flat/empty.

Bottom line: it seems to depend on the word/phrase you are querying.

Comment: This might well be the explanation: if I only supply data for 2013, I apparently only miss data for 2014 for the most correlated search term. (Should have looked closer)